# Deploying a project stored on github to a debian webserver

Tags: git, github, playframework, debian

I'm somewhat new at git (and linux).
I'm part of a small team and tasked with deploying our project to our debian server.

We are still pretty early in the project and thus, do not need an overly complicated deployment solution.

Anyway. Our project is stored on github, which we pull/push from/to.
At the moment, when I want something deployed, I pull it on my Windows machine using git pull.
I then use this script:

```
cd src/www
scp -r app public <user>@<server-ip>:/home/www
```

I enter the password and the files upload.
I then log into the server and restart the service (playframework) `play restart --%prod`

Can anyone recommend a simple solution that makes the server get the changes from github and automatically restarts the server? I've looked around here on stackoverflow and only found solutions that didn't make a lot of sense to me due to my inexperience with Linux and Git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use a deployment library/framework like [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano). Once you configure your deployment (called a "recipe"), Capistrano allows you to deploy to one or more targets very easily from the command line. It also provides a nice release structure, allowing you to better manage the copy of your application that is deployed to your targets at any given moment.

Comment: I have no experience with ruby what so ever, unfortunately. So if that is a requirement, then sadly the solution just got overly complicated. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: There are similar libraries/techniques for other languages, such as deploying with [Phing](http://www.phing.info/) for PHP. The amount of Ruby you would need to know with Capistrano is very low for a simple deployment, and the features you requested are there out of the box with the default deployment recipes.

Comment: Well I was hoping for a more simple solution, but seeing as this answer is the most popular one, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "continuous delivery" to get started. It is not a GitHub specific problem.

One possible setup could be to use the continuous integration server [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). It can be configured to regularly check your GitHub repo for changes. If it finds a change, it can create a build and/or deploy artifacts on an application or a webserver.

Of course, initial setup and maintenance of a continuous integration infrastructure takes time and you have to judge if it is worth the effort. However, it seems to be today state of the art to have something like that in place. You might also be interested in [this post by GitHub devs how they deploy directly by pushing to their repository](https://github.com/blog/1241-deploying-at-github).